# Allow cell population according to other cell's contents

Tags: excel, validation

I am applying Data Validation rules to my data and I would like to accomplish the following:

Set value `X` to a cell if another cell is populated with value `Y`.
For example if in one cell I have `Not a Product Owner`, I want the next cell to be set to `N/A` and be not available for editing. If the first cell includes a value which is different from `Not a Product Owner`, the next cell should be available for editing (with values allowed according to validation rules I've set).

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @PeterL. Since I'm not an excel guru, I only tried to find a solution on the net and since I didn't find anything matching my needs, I asked here. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this may be done using pure Excel: you want preserve condition check and at the same time allow input in the same cell. However, if VBA is an option for you - this is achievable.

Comment: @PeterL. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: Eugene, based on yoiur reply to Peter _ I only tried to find a solution on the net_ have you even read the FAQ, esp "What kind of questions can I ask here?" Voting to close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA way of doing it.

You'll need to put this code in the `Worksheet_Change` event module in the relevant sheet of your workbook.

In short, if a cell in column A is changed to `Not a product owner` then `n/a` is added in column B and the cell is locked for editing. If anything else, a data validation list is added and the cell is unlocked.

Note that this approach requires the sheet to password protected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Options As String
    Options = "1. Choice1, 2. Choice2, 3. Choice3" //Change this options

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Your Password"
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Not a product owner" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = "n/a"
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Options
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Your Password"
End Sub
```