# Conditional Data Validation based on Dropdown List Response

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013 for Windows. I am trying to set up a data validation using VBA code provided in a different thread ([Allow cell population according to other cell's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289462/allow-cell-population-according-to-other-cells-contents)), but am running into issues.

I have a data validation list set up in Column E of the worksheet with list options of "Yes", "No", "N/A". If the user selects "No" or "N/A", I would like "N/A" to automatically appear in Column F and have the cell locked from editing. If the user selects "Yes", then I would like Column F to be unlocked and for the user to be able to enter a number (any number).

Below is the code I am using in VBA. When I run it, I am getting and error that highlights the line of code "If (Target = "No") Or (Target = "N/A") Then" and a box that says "Type Mismatch". Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Your Password"
Application.EnableEvents = False


If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
If (Target = "No") Or (Target = "N/A") Then
Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete
Target.Offset(0, 1) = "n/a"
Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
Else
Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False

End If
End If


Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Your Password"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce your error is to change multiple values in column E with either a paste operation or by typing a value into a multiple select of cells and finishing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. The following will handle multiple changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Unprotect Password:="Your Password"
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target)
            Select Case LCase(rng.Value2)
                Case "no", "n/a"
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = "n/a"
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
                Case "yes"
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
                    Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target).Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Select
                Case Else
                    'cannot be here. do nothing
            End Select
        Next rng
    End If

bm_safe_exit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
        Me.Protect Password:="Your Password"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I've reorganized some lines in your code and made the unprotect and event disable process only if a change or changes is/are within column E. I also swapped out your `If ...` statement for a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) as I find these more representative of the type of conditions you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much! Jeeped -- this approach solved my problem. The conditional data validation is functioning correctly now. Really appreciate both of your help!

Comment: Glad that worked out. Since I've had time to think, clearing one or more entries (tapping the [Del] key) will have the effect of the `Case Else`. I don't know if you want to reinstate the data validation and clear the value from column F there or not but it should probably be handled somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure what that means. Do you have any specific recommendations for that?

Also, could you please advise on how to apply this same VBA code to other columns where I'm applying the same conditional data validation?

Comment: ① If E5 has already been set as **Yes** then subsequently deleting Yes will remove it from E5 but F5 is still unlocked. If E5 was **No** or **N/A** and the value was cleared, F5 would still be **n/a**. There should be something that resets F5 to its original state within the `Case Else` but I don't know enough about the original data validation to make a suggestion. ② If you just want the exact same thing to happen (e.g. `n/a`, remove validation, lock or unlock) then a simple [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) will do on the intersect.

Comment: Thanks, @jeeped

1) The original data validation is a simple dropdown list linked to a range of 3 cells hosting each of the 3 options (yes, no, n/a). This list is in a separate worksheet.

2) I tried to use the Union method, but it did not work: 
`If Not Intersect(Union(Range("E:E"), (Range("G:G") Target)) Is Nothing Then`

I also tried: 
`If Not Intersect(Range("E:E, G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

This works only for one of the columns, and it seems to change the column that works at random as I open and close the workbook. 

Any additional suggestions you have would be appreciated!

Comment: You were pretty close. Either `If Not Intersect(Union(Range("E:E"), Range("G:G")),  Target)` or `If Not Intersect(Range("E:E, G:G"), Target) ` should do the trick. The latter uses a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)'s abilty to union with a single string refernce (but ONLY a single string refernce).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Target` is defined as a Range (`ByVal Target as Range`). Try replacing your if statements with `If (Target.Value = "No") Or (Target.Value = "N/A") Then`

edit: Hm, I don't get the error when just using `Target`.  If you put a line break at that line (with your cursor in the line, press F9), what happens when you change a value in column E?  I suspect it has to do with the Data Validation being used.

Edit2: Hm, it works with my data validation too.  Can you post some same data perhaps, or a screenshot of your column E (the relevant area)?