# Excel drop down lists and average function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, dropdown

Currently, I have a formula that helps me calculate an average depending on two drop down lists.  I managed it so that the average is calculated even when any one of the drop down lists are empty.

Screen capture of current two-drop-down arrangement:

[image: Excel Capture]

I would now like to do the same thing but this time have an average function that works with 3 drop down lists: I want it to return the value that corresponds when 1, 2 or 3 of the drop down cells are selected.

I somehow get lost when writing the formula and it returns an error. I feel that I am not considering all the possibilities.

Can you help me out?

Thank you :)

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're wanting to add in the names criteria from your picture, I came up with the following formula. It's pretty long and there may be a cleaner way, but seems to work.

```
`=IFERROR(IF(AND(A5<>"",B5="",C5=""),AVERAGEIF(Name,A5,Number),
  IF(AND(A5="",B5<>"",C5=""),AVERAGEIF(size,B5,Number),
  IF(AND(A5="",B5="",C5<>""),AVERAGEIF(color,C5,Number),
  IF(AND(A5<>"",B5<>"",C5=""),AVERAGEIFS(Number,Name,A5,size,B5),
  IF(AND(A5<>"",B5="",C5<>""),AVERAGEIFS(Number,Name,A5,color,C5),
  IF(AND(A5="",B5<>"",C5<>""),AVERAGEIFS(Number,size,B5,color,C5),
  AVERAGEIFS(Number,Name,A5,size,B5,color,C5))))))),
  "No Combo")`
```

Comment: Harder to read but it works just as well. Suggestion: use [Ctrl]+K to quickly indent your code/formulas four spaces rather than 'back-ticking' them. Save the 'back-ticks' for in-line formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have four conditions that can be met and error control for when mismatched conditions produce no results.

> 1. A5, B5 and C5 can all have values.
> 2. Neither A5, B5 nor C5 have values.
> 3. Two of the A5:C5 cells can have values.
>
>    - A5 is blank
>    - B5 is blank
>    - C5 is blank
> 4. One of the A5:C5 cells can have values.
>
>    - A5 has a value
>    - B5 has a value
>    - C5 has a value
> 5. Any combination of A5, B5 and C5 (including blank) produces no matching numbers from D9:D14 resulting in a `#DIV/0!` error from the [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690).

The standard formula in D5 is,

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTA(A5:C5)=3, AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, A9:A14, A5, B9:B14, B5, C9:C14, C5),
         IF(COUNTA(A5:C5)=0, AVERAGE(D9:D14),
         IF(COUNTA(A5:C5)=2, IF(A5="", AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, B9:B14, B5, C9:C14, C5),
                             IF(B5="", AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, A9:A14, A5, C9:C14, C5),
                                       AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, A9:A14, A5, B9:B14, B5))),
         IF(COUNTA(A5:C5)=1, IF(A5<>"", AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, A9:A14, A5),
                             IF(B5<>"", AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, B9:B14, B5),
                                        AVERAGEIFS(D9:D14, C9:C14, C5))))))),
         "nothing to avg")
```

You may elect to keep the linefeeds and extra spacing in the formula. There are not detrimental and help to organize the formula visually.

[image: listbox_average]

I've only used the [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) and [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) functions for simplicity. The [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) function is just an AVERAGEIFS with only one criteria but it has its parameters flipped around to compensate for the option that the *average_range* may not be the same range as the *criteria_range*. With AVERAGEIFS, a separate *average_range* and *criteria_range* is not optional. Using only AVERAGEIFS when criteria was involved means that you can use one syntax.

This is a bit more complex than your original which only allowed for a single criteria. With more criteria comes the increased likelihood for more `DIV/0!` errors. To limit the choices based on other choices, see [Conditional Data Validation based on Dropdown List Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423927/conditional-data-validation-based-on-dropdown-list-response/33424484#33424484) for ideas.